# How best to iterate over a list when a each list item will be passed to a function?

Tags: python, function, iteration

The ipaddress module contains an IPv4Network function which can be used to determine if an IPv4 address is reserved e.g.

```
In [25]: IPv4Address(u'100.64.1.1') in IPv4Network(u'100.64.0.0/10')
Out[25]: True
```

The above is just one range; there are several ranges of reserved IP addresses. I want to check that a given address is in ***any***. The long-winded way of doing this would be to put all the ranges in a list, then iterate over the list and repeat the above check e.g.

```
def isPrivate(ipaddress):
    for range in ranges:
        if ipaddress in IPv4Network(range):
            print 'private'
```

There seems to be a smarter way to do **everything** in Python; is there a smarter way to do this, or a construct I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`range` is a Python builtin, so it's not a good idea to shadow it with a local variable. I've used `r` here instead

```
def isPrivate(ipaddress):
    if any(ipaddress in IPv4Network(r) for r in ranges):
        print 'private'
```

If there is a possibility of more than one match, you can count them by replacing `any` with `sum`

```
private_count = sum(ipaddress in IPv4Network(r) for r in ranges)
```

since `True` values count as `1`

Comment: This is slightly different behaviour as it only prints `private` at most once. I know that's probably what is needed.

Comment: @PeterWood, I assumed the ranges weren't overlapping

Comment: Sure, just noting it.

Comment: @PeterWood use `filter` instead of `any` if overlapping exists

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean 'reserved', but IPv4Address class has **is_private** and **is_reserved** attributes which can satisfy your needs

Comment: Judging from the OP, the example `100.64.1.1` should be considered private.

Comment: @Alex C. Convenient, thank you. See an issue I'm having with this though here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30996001/python-ipaddress-addressvalueerror-at-least-3-parts-expected