# Python: ipaddress.AddressValueError: At least 3 parts expected

Tags: python, string, unicode, ip-address

An attribute of `ipaddress.IPv4Network` can be used to check if any IP address is reserved.

In IPython:

```
In [52]: IPv4Address(u'169.254.255.1').is_private
Out[52]: False
```

Yet if I try the exact same thing in a function:

```
import ipaddress
def isPrivateIp(ip):
    unicoded = unicode(ip)
    if ipaddress.IPv4Network(unicoded).is_private or ipaddress.IPv6Network(unicoded).is_private:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print isPrivateIp(r'169.254.255.1')
```

I get:

```
  File "isPrivateIP.py", line 13, in <module>
    print isPrivateIp(ur'169.254.255.1')
  File "isPrivateIP.py", line 7, in isPrivateIp
    if ipaddress.IPv4Network(unicoded).is_private or ipaddress.IPv6Network(unicoded).is_private:
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipaddress.py", line 2119, in __init__
    self.network_address = IPv6Address(self._ip_int_from_string(addr[0]))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipaddress.py", line 1584, in _ip_int_from_string
    raise AddressValueError(msg)
ipaddress.AddressValueError: At least 3 parts expected in u'169.254.255.1'
```

Why is this the case?

Note: In python 2, ip addresses must be passed to `ipaddress` functions as unicode objects, hence calling `unicode()` on the string input `ip`.

Comment: Your code snippets are not equivalent, you can clearly see that exception is related with `IPv6Address` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected input for `ipaddress.IPv6Network()` is different than `ipaddress.IPv4Network()`. If you remove `or ipaddress.IPv6Network(unicoded).is_private` from your code it works fine. You can read more from [here](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/ipaddress.html).